# Metadata (CSW) server + editor alternative to GeoNetwork?

Tags: metadata, geonetwork, csw

Can anyone suggest an alternative to GeoNetwork for editing/searching and displaying via a graphical interface?

I quite like it but the "manual update" docs are empty http://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/trunk/eng/users/maintainer-guide/updating/manual-update.html and fetching a new 3.2.1 war and pointing it to the old database and copying through trial and error different things from the data folder of the old installation yields blank metadata edit pages, at the best.

Recreating users and metadata permissions and groups and categories isn't so fun so I was wondering if there's an alternative people might recommend?

Comment: You might give this site a shot for a little more 'upgrade' detail: http://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/bev/doc/gn-install/geonet_maintenance.html

Comment: You could always add your discoveries to the manual or pay someone to write the manual for you or to do your upgrade for you

Comment: A list of unresolved issues doesn't really belong in the manual. There is a query on the geonetwork users mailing list, parts of it might need a bug report. As for the upgrade detail, thanks, but it isn't correct in terms of the data folder (at least to apply to my scenario): the structure and contents differ between 2.10 and 3. It also doesn't detail that you need to restore your database connection details. Yes, in the end I might need to pay someone, it's just that this should be a fairly common procedure.

Comment: Why don't you export all the records as full ISO 19139 XML, create a new system then import all the XML, all your data should be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

To update GeoNetwork you just have to deploy the new war with the same database and folder configurations. GeoNetwork takes care automatically of the upgrading.

As an alternative, there  is currently no alternative that has all the power of the metadata editor in GeoNetwork (neither closed source of open sourced). If you are ok with a simpler editor, you can try GeoNode.